# Trying to debug c++ through vscode

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Im studying c++ and im having a big problem debugging in vscode since everytime i try to debug i get this error
*The preLaunchTask 'C/C++':g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1*
I never have problems with compiling it but the debugger seems to be useless.
whenever i print though like one simple task such as
cout << "hello"<<endl;
the debugger seems to work.

after this display i click on the button "debug anyway" and it tells me launch: program 'c:\Users...\main.exe' does not exist.
this is my launch.json file:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
    }
]
}
```

I'm so desperate about it i've been trying to sort it out for days now. (checking on other articles in stackoverflow, reinstalling vscode etc.)

Comment: Is main.exe the name of the executable produced?

Comment: ***I'm so desperate about it i've been trying to sort it out for days now*** You likely need to spend some more time to figure out what is happening. What file name is produced when you compile your code? Does the debugger run when you execute it from the command line?

Comment: Is "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe" the correct path of the debugger?

Comment: Beginner programmers often write code without compilation errors, compared to the senior programmers.

Comment: @drescherjm
Hey thank you for your comments. I checked it already and it is in the right path.
i pasted it to the regular visual studio and everything works fine :/ once i find the solution i will upload it

Comment: Try to run gdb on your executable from a cmd.exe window

Answer (score 0):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

- preLaunchTask - to launch a task before the start of a debug session, set this attribute to the label of a task specified in tasks.json (in the workspace's .vscode folder). Or, this can be set to ${defaultBuildTask} to use your default build task.

We can't see your tasks.json file but my suggestion is to set the value in preLaunchTask to ${defaultBuildTask}.

The documentation on Visual Studio Code is pretty good.